# The Powershell hangs after a command execution

Tags: powershell

From time to time, though rather frequently, my Powershell console hangs after a (both successful and unsuccessful) command execution. I use the Powershell version 2.0.-1.-1 for the Sharepoint 2010 management on the Windows Server 2008 R2. When I press enter after (or during) a command execution (the end I can guess from the CPU utilization obviously) the console shows command prompt and result or error.

Comment: Does this happend with all scripts/commands or just a specific one? If one, share the code. If not, then this is probably better suited in Super User. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: It happens with for instance Get-SPSite or Restore-SPSite Sharepoint commands but occurs also when ps1 scripts are executed. Okay, I'll ask on Superuser community.